# Rename [gpt] (Google Publisher Tag) to avoid confusion with ChatGPT

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-disambiguation, chatgpt

### Problem

The tag [gpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpt) is ambiguous with its current name.

The [gpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpt) tag (Google Publisher Tag) has nothing to do with AI. However, questions that are ChatGPT/[GPT-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpt-3) related show up.

#### Proposed Solution

I already expanded the excerpt, but it can't be certain everyone is going to read it before using it (see the [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) tag).

Therefore, the tag should be renamed to *google-gpt*. We already have [google-chrome-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools) and [google-ajax-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-ajax-libraries). So putting the "google"-part in front would be the in line with the other Google-related tags.

Alternatively, *google-publisher-tag* would be a good fit. Though I would prefer the first one as the term GPT is used in the [official documentation by Google](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/guides/get-started) and it is less to type. :)

Also clean up of [gpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpt) is required.

Comment: "but it can't be certain everyone is going to read it before using it" - it can be certain the vast majority of people _won't_ read it. Tag wikis are shockingly useless

Comment: Just a heads-up, I cleaned up a few questions and created [tag:generative-pretrained-transformer] tag as a general GPT tag since there are only [tag:gpt-2] and [tag:gpt-3] but no other GPTs tag. Perhaps further discussion about various GPTs may be needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Implemented Solution

As pointed out in the comments, the [google-publisher-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-publisher-tag)-tag already existed. The tags have been merged, though the wiki is lost. I recovered the wiki and excerpt, but as I am below [20 000 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) it needs to be peer-reviewed.

#### To Do

- Tag still needs some cleanup.
- Tag wiki requires <s>approval: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33414116</s> rewriting (Why? The old wiki was apparently copied from somewhere without source→ my suggest reinstating it has been rejected)
- <s>Tag excerpt requires approval: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33414117</s> approved