# Disambiguate [chatgpt] and [openai]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation, chatgpt

I just noticed that on the SO we have [chatgpt] and [openai].

Some questions, like [Error when fetching on chatgpt api, error 429](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75049140), are about https://api.openai.com/v1/completions not about https://chat.openai.com/chat. Questions like this, I think should be tagged with [openai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openai) instead of [chatgpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt).

What do you think?

## [chatgpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt) 19 questions

Tag Wiki: Not available

## [openai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openai) 305 questions

### Tag Wiki

#### Excerpt

> OpenAI is an artificial intelligence research laboratory. It consists of the for-profit corporation and conducts research in the field of artificial intelligence (AI) promoting and developing friendly AI that benefits everyone.

#### Body

> Not available

---

Some questions about https://chat.openai.com/chat tagged with [chatgpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt) are off-topic and already closed as "not about programming..." like

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/74976690/1595451
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/75037578/1595451
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/75048188/1595451
- [what machine learning model is used in chatgpt application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75078631/1595451)
- [How can ChatGPT API support multiple conversations with an account?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75119223/1595451)
- [ChatGPT Fine Tuning a model with custom dataset and expect answers from the data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75123412/1595451)

Comment: The tag [tag:openai] shouldn't exist, at least not as currently described in the tag wiki you quote. We don't do *company* tags (see multiple prior burninations). There may be appropriate technologies and/or APIs which OpenAI created which can/should have tags, but the *company* shouldn't have a tag.

Comment: I haven't investigated what the questions in that tag consist of. The [tag:openai] tag is *very* clearly about the company, based on the tag excerpt which you've quoted. From a 5 second look, and some prior knowledge, it seems reasonable that there be a tag such as [tag:openai-api], but if what's needed is just a rename or if it's something that needs a complete burnination is going to depend on how it was used by the vast majority of the questions which use the existing [tag:openai] tag.

Comment: @Makyen I haven't found questions tagged [tag:openai] about the company but I can't tell for sure that all the 305 questions with this tag are properly tagged. Anyway, I added an answer with some additional details.

Comment: ChatGPT has no public API yet, so I don't see how there can be _on-topic_ questions with that tag.

Comment: Semi-related: We do have a [generative-pretrained-transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generative-pretrained-transformer) tag, as well as [gpt-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpt-2) & [gpt-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpt-3). See comments on [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422097/rename-gpt-google-publisher-tag-to-avoid-confusion-with-chatgpt).

Comment: This edit should be a new question.
This is getting extremely hard to keep track of. Your edit invalidated existing answers, and the votes don't reflect the current question status.

Comment: Just in case you don't see the response to your flag... While I'm happy to see you taking feedback into account and modifying your request accordingly, it does become confusing and problematic to edit a question and modify your proposal when it has already been answered. Therefore, I would (again, like Cerbrus) recommend that you *ask a new question* (including a link to this one, in order to provide context, if you think that would be helpful) to request what you now feel is the best course of action. This one can even be marked as a duplicate of that one, to consolidate the discussion.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I deleted my old answers as they didn't have comments from others, they look to be obsolete and no longer necessary and updating them be annoying. Also I think that the tag rename, at this time, is no longer necessary.

Comment: Marking this as completed now. After the manual disambiguation was completed, I've gone ahead and made [chatgpt] and the newly-emerged tag [chat-gpt] synonyms of [openai].

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not sure this is better. Now, there's no easy filter to find off-topic ChatGPT questions, as they're merged into everything [openai]... Just now I found 3 questions about "ChatGPT" that were actually just about older models.

Comment: I don't understand your objection, @Cerbrus. [You were the one who did most of the work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422592) to remove uses of the [chatgpt] tag.

Comment: @CodyGray I know, it's just much harder to filter them with a synonym, than without. Without, you just filter on the bad tag, and new questions are the only ones shown. With the synonym, there's no way to actively filter for questions about ChatGPT.

Comment: But why is that any worse than just sorting the questions by newest, @Cerbrus? Is it the case that the majority of questions that people would tag [chatgpt] are off-topic but *not* for questions tagged [openai]? I imagine that both would be relatively gold-mines of off-topic questions.

Comment: @CodyGray a lot of GPT and OpenAI API questions get tagged with [openai], and those are perfectly valid. It's not a major issue, but it's way easier to see just [chatgpt] questions, than having to open every single new [openai] one :D

Answer (score 19):

I [went through](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus?tab=activity&sort=revisions) those 19 questions tagged [chatgpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt):

[image]

Only ***2*** of them were actually about ChatGPT (posted by the same user, using [`cURL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) to make requests directly to ChatGPT)

Every single question outside of those 2 were either:

- Accessing OpenAI's API, but using *older* language models

  - I retagged those to the correct language model, predominantly [gpt-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpt-3)
- *"I asked ChatGPT but it didn't help me"* - kind of remarks

  - I removed [chatgpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt) from those and removed the *"I asked the AI"* line, as that's irrelevant.
- Completely off-topic, nonsense, or otherwise not suitable for this site.

One of the 2 remaining questions was answered with an answer that used OpenAI's public GPT-3 API, which, once again, isn't ChatGPT.

So yea, There's hardly any usecase for the [chatgpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt) tag. I just can't quite justify removing the tag from the remaining 2 questions yet.

Comment: Are they not generic HTTP request / response parsing questions that just happen to target the ChatGPT site? Looks like it to me.

Comment: @Gimby Well, there is some GTP-related logic, but if you think that it doesn't need that tag, maybe it can be removed

Comment: Probably the OP of the 2 questions left tagged with [tag:chatgpt] took the code from https://www.codingthesmartway.com/how-to-use-chatgpt-with-react/ I'm not familiar enough yet  to really know if the use  of "chatgpt" is appropriate.

Comment: @Rubén no, that's using OPenAI's API for a older model.

Comment: I compared the code from 2 questions the code form the link in my previus comment the besides the strings for the API key on both questions and console.log statement on one of them, they are identical. Looking at the npm page of the openai module it's a package to for the Open AI API ... it's not really using nothing of  ChatGPT (the web app) so I removed [tag:chatgpt] and added [tag:express] and [tag:curl] to these questions that are more appropriate.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that any question that includes the phrase "I asked chatgpt" should be closed.

Comment: Oh, indeed, they were using openAI's API, which is GPT-3

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday [chat-gpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat-gpt) appeared, was cleaned and reappeared today probably because someone added a question before the tag was purged.

Apparently this tag was created when [What are the differences between OpenAI ChatGPT and Google Bard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75382627/1595451) was posted. This question and [Open AI ChatGPT Training](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75409600/1595451) that was posted today are actually about ChatGPT, but since both questions are off-topic, and the tag name is misspelled as it looks to refer to ChatGPT, it should not include a dash, and I removed the tag from these questions.

Also I removed this tag from other questions, because they mentioned that they have *asked to ChatGPT*, they used the term ChatGPT as a common name to refer to the OpenAI API, etc., but they were not on-topic questions about https://chat.openai.com/chat.

---

More questions that at some point were tagged [chat-gpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat-gpt) (newest first)

- [Is there a way to prompt ChatGPT to translate natural lauguage requests to predefined program functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75418605/1595451)
- [Does this ChatGPT "swap" snippet do anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75415943/1595451)
- [How can I call the chatgpt api in Google Chrome Extension？](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75408152/1595451)
- [how can I integrate PIM API with ChatGPT API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75383788/1595451)

Answer (score 1):

Considering [Makyen's comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422589/disambiguate-chatgpt-and-openai/422746#comment942525_422589) and that the questions with the [openai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openai) tag aren't about the company, but rather about the OpenAI API...

The [openai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openai) tag wiki has been updated. New tag excerpt:

> Use for questions about the OpenAI API.