# Should [chatgpt-api] become a synonym of [openai-api]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

[chatgpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt) [is already a synonym](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422589/disambiguate-chatgpt-and-openai) of [openai-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openai-api) (as well as [openai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openai)).

I stumbled across [chatgpt-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt-api) which only has 32 questions currently (29 of which with the `openai-api` tag as well...). It is likely to come up again if deleted, so instead of retagging I believe a synonym is in place (seems reasonable considering the existing synonym relation).

As I have no score in this tags, I can't suggest a synonym, so raised a request here.

Comment: Related: [Disambiguate \[chatgpt\] and \[openai\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422589)

Comment: Please no. The tag is very useful in filtering out questions that are actually about ChatGPT in general.

Comment: I agree with @Cerbrus. The OpenAI API may encompass ChatGPT, but a lot of the questions in the category are related to non-ChatGPT topics, which is a more specific scope.

Comment: My brain hurts. Shouldn't the chatgpt tag then not be a synonym of chatgpt-api?

Comment: @Gimby My thoughts also. I don't know how to check but I suspect [tag:chatgpt-api] was created ***after*** the mentioned clean-up of the other tags

Comment: @Tomerikoo [created 12 days ago](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11RTe.png)

Comment: @VLAZ Funny... All this time and I never noticed that exists. Thanks! And it does confirm my suspicion. The linked discussion was last active one month ago